# How do I insert keyframe to match my physics simulation?

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I am trying to learn python for blender and a good place to start would be by creating a physics engine.

I made a function that uses F = ma to calculate the position and velocity of an object using the mass, force, initial position and initial velocity.

```
import bpy

mass = 1.0
substeps = 5
initial_velocity = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]


timestep = 1/(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.fps * substeps)

def simulate(force = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], position = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], velocity = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]):
    x = position[0]
    y = position[1]
    z = position[2]
    vx = velocity[0]
    vy = velocity[1]
    vz = velocity[2]
    acceleration = [force[0]/mass, force[1]/mass, force[2]/mass]
    for j in range(substeps):
        vx += acceleration[0] * timestep
        vy += acceleration[1] * timestep
        vz += acceleration[2] * timestep
        x += vx * timestep
        y += vy * timestep
        z += vz * timestep
    return [[x, y, z], [vx, vy, vz]]


current_speed = initial_velocity


for bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_current in range(10,240):
    simulation_data = [[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
    simulation_data = simulate([(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].gravity[0] * mass), (bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].gravity[1] * mass), (bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].gravity[2] * mass)] , bpy.data.objects["Sphere"].location, current_speed)
    bpy.data.objects["Sphere"].location = simulation_data[0]
    bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Location')
    current_speed = simulation_data[1]
```

I have added unnecessary variables for better understanding, I will remove them.
Running this script makes the ball nudge a bit but it does not move over different frames.

Comment: Two dupes show two options either use `scene.frame_set(frame)` to set the frame, or `ob.keyframe_insert(data_path, frame=frame)` to insert a kf on frame. Btw with vectors can `F = mass * scene.gravity` rather than splitting into components

Comment: That was a big help. Thank you sir